# JS Object PUG iteration issue in Express.js

Tags: express, pug

I'm stuck with an issue. Let me give you some details before I dive into it.
I'm learning so this is not a real project. Second, the application is based on tutorial from acadmind video tutorials on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56TizEw2LgI&list=PL55RiY5tL51rajp7Xr_zk-fCFtzdlGKUp) and here is the github link (https://github.com/pin2plane/Academind-nodejs-shopping-cart)
That tutorial is built using hbs templating framework. I'm trying to build the same project with PUG. I ran into an iteration issue:

We have the cart.add function:

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
this.items = oldCart.items || {};
this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || 0;
this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0

this.add = function (item, id) {
    //If the item exists in the stored item, go to increase the qty, price of that item line
    //Also update the totalQty and totalPrice


    var storedItem = this.items[id];
    //if the item not there, then add the item to the empty items object
    if (!storedItem) {
        storedItem = this.items[id] = { item: item, qty: 0, price: 0 };
    }

    storedItem.qty++;
    storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
    this.totalQty++;
    this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price;
};
```

Focus on this line:

```
 storedItem = this.items[id] = { item: item, qty: 0, price: 0 };
```

As you can see, the object properties consist of item[object, object], qty and price

The shopping-cart.hbs view is this:

```
{{# if products }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
            {{# each products }}
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="badge">{{ this.qty }}</span>
                    <strong>{{ this.item.title }}</strong>
                    <span class="label label-success">${{ this.price }}</span>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/reduce/{{this.item._id}}">Reduce by 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/remove/{{this.item._id}}">Remove All</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is with the dropdown button that display the reduce by 1 and remove all.

Here is my pug file (the products is passed to the view from the route handler)

```
     div.row
       div.col-lg-6.clearfix.offset-2.border
         p.badge.badge-warning.float-right Quantity #{product.qty}
         p  Total price: #{product.price} &nbsp
         each val in product
           p #{val.title} 
           p DB Item ID : #{val._id}
           .dropdown
               button.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='dropdown', aria-haspopup='true', aria-expanded='false') Action
                 ul.dropdown-menu
                   li
                     a.dropdown-item(href='#') Reduce By 1
                   li
                     a.dropdown-item(href='#') Remove All
```

The output is this:
[image]

As you can see the iteration goes over the {item :item, qty :, price: }
But because I need access to the item._id (val._id), I can't move the buttons outside of this div, unless there is another way to get the item id so I can pass it to my route handler that handles the reduce by 1 and remove all functionality.

As I said in the beginning, the code works 100 % with hbs so it's not the route or express, it is pure pug issue, the iteration works fine because I'm able to access every product in the cart object and display title, id and everything

It's accessing the id and passing it to the button that I spent the last two days trying to figure out how to pass the id to the button with out iterating over the object but couldn't figure it out

If there is a pug ninja out there with experience in how to accomplish this, it would be so much appreciated to show me what I'm doing wrong or how to set this up correctly to match the same functionality the hbs file provides.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the each val in product because you don't need to iterate over the object. All you have to do is move the dropdown div for the ACTION button group to under the badge line and access the item id using #{product.item._id}